# Python Mathematical signs in function parameter?

Tags: python, function, math, symbols, sign

I would like to know if there is a way to add math symbols into the function parameters.

```
def math(x, y, symbol):
      answer = x 'symbol' y
      return answer
```

this is an small example what I mean.

**EDIT:
here is the whole problem**

```
def code_message(str_val, str_val2, symbol1, symbol2):
    for char in str_val:

        while char.isalpha() == True:
            code = int(ord(char))
            if code < ord('Z'):
                code symbol1= key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            elif code > ord('z'):
                code symbol1= key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            elif code > ord('A'):
                code symbol2= key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            elif code < ord('a'):
                code symbol2= key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            break
        if char.isalpha() == False:
            str_val2 += char
    return str_val2
```

I need to call the function a number of times but sometimes with a +/- for first symbol and sometimes a +/- for second symbol

ORIGINAL CODE :

```
def code_message(str_val, str_val2):
    for char in str_val:

        while char.isalpha() == True:
            code = int(ord(char))
            if code < ord('Z'):
                code -= key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            elif code > ord('z'):
                code -= key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            elif code > ord('A'):
                code += key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            elif code < ord('a'):
                code += key
                str_val2 += str(chr(code))
            break
        if char.isalpha() == False:
            str_val2 += char
    return str_val2
```

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate a bit more

Comment: did you mean `answer = x "symbol" y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not pass operator to the function, but however you may pass operator's functions defined in [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) library. Hence, your function will be like:

```
>>> from operator import eq, add, sub
>>> def magic(left, op, right):
...     return op(left, right)
...
```

**Examples**:

```
# To Add
>>> magic(3, add, 5)
8
# To Subtract
>>> magic(3, sub, 5)
-2
# To check equality
>>> magic(3, eq, 3)
True
```

**Note**: I am using function as `magic` instead of `math` because `math` is default python library and it is not good practice to use predefined keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Use the corresponding functions, from `operator` module:

```
from operator import add
def math(x, y, add):
      answer = add(x, y)
      return answer
```

The only way that you can pass a mathematics sign to a function is passing is in string mode, then you'd have two problems, evaluating the sign and the equation as well. So when you are dealing with numbers you better to use a proper functions to does the job directly.

You can also use a dictionary to map the symbols to the corresponding function:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul
mapping = {"+": add, "-":sub, "*": mul}
def math(x, y, sym):
    try:
        f = mapping[sym]
    except KeyError:
        raise Exception("Enter a valid operator")
    else:
        answer = f(x, y)
        return answer
```

Comment: And what to do with `add(x, y) = answer` being a syntax error?

Comment: `answer = add(x,y)`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Just, a copy past mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised noone mentioned `eval()`. Look at the example below:

```
def function(operator1, operator2, symbol):
    return eval(str(operator1) + symbol + str(operator2))

print(function(2, 3, '+'))      # prints: 5
print(function(2, 3, '-'))      # prints: -1

# Of course you can also "chain" operations, e.g., for 4 + 5 - 6
result = function(function(4, 5, '+'), 6, '-')
print(result)                   # prints 3

# Finally, it also works with string input for the operands so you 
# can read them directly from e.g., user input with `input()`
print(function('2', '3', '+'))  # prints: 5
```

Comment: `eval` is the function which is never recommended to be used in the program. It will work, but it is not recommended. In fact, according to me, `eval` functions can anytime may turn into virus and you won't even know what went wrong

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri "With great power comes great responsibility" would be my comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should first consider that you have to use `answer = x symbol y` and not the contrary.

Then concerning the use of symbols, you can send the function as a parameter.
For the basic operator you might use the [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module.

For example:

```
import operator

def math(x, y, function):
      return function(x, y)

math(4,5, operator.sub)
```

You will find in the documentation all the others operations you need.