# Why does the TypeError exception not work in this definition?

Tags: python, typeerror, try-except

I'm making a function to help me during an exam, that should tell me which data type you get when you combine two datatypes a certain way. You should also be able to tell if it is going to produce an error, so I wrote the following code:

```
a = '123'
b = 123

def check(data):
    try:
        print(type(data))
    except TypeError as error:
        print(f'Error: {error}')

check(a+b)
```

But instead of returning the exception, I get an error message saying "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str". Why is the try/except fuction not working?

Comment: Because `a+b` is evaluated when the function is called, not when the code enters the `try` block.

Comment: *"I'm making a function to help me during an exam"* are you taking this exam **right now**? This sounds a lot like you are asking us to help you cheat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check what happens when you combine two objects safely you need to perform the combination inside the try block:

```py
def check(a, b):
    try:
        print(f'Trying to combine types {type(a)} and {type(b)}')
        c = a + b
        print(f'Resulting type: {type(c)}'))
    except TypeError as error:
        print(f'Error: {error}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `a+b` is evaluated in the line `check(a+b)`, where there is no exception handling.

Below is one way you could achieve what you're trying to do using meta programming where you pass the operator function as an argument to the `check` function. The inconvenient part here is that you can't pass the `+` operator directly so you have to define a separate function. Or alternatively you could use the `operator` library as described in [Python Mathematical signs in function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204420/python-mathematical-signs-in-function-parameter)

```
a = '123'
b = 123

# ====================
def add(a, b):
    return (a+b)


# ====================
def check(data1, data2, combination_method):
    try:
        result = combination_method(data1, data2)
        print(type(result))
    except TypeError as error:
        print(f'Error: {error}')


check(a, b, add)
```